# PREFETCHNTA makes no difference -- is it coded correctly?

Tags: assembly, memory-management, x86-64, cpu-cache, prefetch

I am working on an application that uses AVX-512 instructions.  The app takes a large qword array (400MB or larger) and processes it 64 bytes at a time.   I use multiple threads, and each thread is pinned to a separate core.

The first instruction of the main loop is to read 8 qwords into zmm1.  On each new iteration, each core reads the next 8 qwords using a stride equal to 64 x the number of cores.  For example, with 4 cores, the stride for each core is 256 bytes.

Unfortunately, the access pattern is random due to the OS scheduling cores in random order, and without cache control the program runs 10 times faster with only a single core than with multiple cores.

To get cache control, I'm using PREFETCHNTA, coded like this:

```
VCVTTPD2QQ zmm1,[r11+r15]

mov rax,r15
add rax,[stride]
cmp rax,r10
jge label_8010
add rax,r11
PREFETCHNTA byte[rax]

label_8010:
```

where r15 is the loop counter, r11 is the base pointer to the large array and r10 is the length of the large array (we can't read past that).  Following each read, I add the current value of the loop counter and the stride to the base pointer and call PREFETCHNTA.

But the run time does not change, so as coded the block for PREFETCHNTA shown above does nothing.  I expected it to prefetch each 64 bytes one stride ahead on each iteration, but it doesn't do that.

My question is whether my coding above is the correct way to code for PREFETCHNTA?

Comment: Hardware prefetch can already detect strided access patterns (specifically the L2 streamer).  Also, out of order exec will already be doing a demand load for 1 stride ahead so that's pointless.  Tuning the prefetch distance is hard (and depends on hardware and system load details) but 1 iteration is definitely way too short.

Comment: To followup on Peter’s comment, multiply stride by some constant so you’re prefetching more than one iteration ahead. Keep increasing the constant until you see a performance change. If you don’t see an improvement, then you know the hardware prefetcher is doing a good enough job.